# HipChat 4 not working in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: 18.04

I have installed Hipchat 4 in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. But when I try to launch the Hipchat I am getting following error:

```
Unable to access hipchat.com. Please check that your network is 
connected and try again
```

Comment: What's the outcome of `getent hosts hipchat.com` ?

Comment: 34.196.186.19   hipchat.com
52.200.184.61   hipchat.com
50.17.44.232    hipchat.com

Comment: Hmm, that looks OK. Please attach more logs.

Comment: Does the site work in the browser? This sounds like a temporary internet routing issue.

Comment: The site works on the browser but does not work in the Desktop App.

Comment: This is a Hipchat issue; you will need to wait for a fix from Atlassian. The current version is not compatible with the openssl libs provided by Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo rm /opt/HipChat4/lib/libcrypto.so* && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 /opt/HipChat4/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 && sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0 /opt/HipChat4/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0

Comment: Seems to be [HCPUB-6249](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/HCPUB-6249); please go there for discussion.